# Set specific width for Python label as this many pixels long?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Python program, and I am looking for ways to make a nice centre-aligned title at the top of inside my program. However, I am having trouble doing this because with the current tools I have, I would have to experiment my label spacing length to match how many characters I have for my title. Is there a way to make a Python label be certain amount of pixels long regardless of length of the text? I am specifically looking for a way of specifically making a label be a specific number of pixels long so I don't have to experiment with all these different lengths.

I tried using the "padx" and "pady" parameters, but I have found that the lengths will always change depending on the length of the text of the label itself. I also tried the "width" parameter, but it only extends by a number of textlengths long.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

label_toptitle = Label(root,
                   text="Program Name",
                   padx=40,
                   pady=40,
                   font=(None, 40),
                   #height=2,
                   #width=30
                   )
root.mainloop()
```

This is my current code right here, but if I change the name "Program Name" to another name, the padx and pady and/or width or height functions will become not the same amount of pixels long. I need a way to make the label a fixed amount of pixels long.

Comment: This can't be all of your current code, because this label wouldn't be visible.

Comment: You have not placed your label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title mentions setting the length of a label, but it seems your real goal is to center a label without having to calculate margins.

The best solution for that is to not use padding or margins to center the widget. Just tell tkinter you want things centered when you use `grid` or `pack`, which is actually the default. You don't have to do much at all.

For example, the following will give a window with a centered title:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

label_toptitle = tk.Label(root,
                          text="Program Name",
                          font=(None, 40),
)
label_toptitle.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Grid can center things too, though the exact syntax depends on what other rows and columns you have. Without knowing that it's hard to give a useful example.

If you *really* need to specify an exact width in pixels for a label, you can add a transparent one-pixel image to the label and hide it behind the text. When you add an image, the `width` attribute represents a width in pixels rather than characters.

Example:

```
pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
label = tk.Label(root, image=pixel, text="Hello", compound="center", width=100)
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit the parameters of "label_toptitle.pack" to set such label as a specific width of number of pixels long?

Comment: @RonZhang: no, you can not set parameters of `pack` to force the widget to a specific size, but you can set the widget itself to a specific size. You have to give it an image (and you'll need to use the `compound` option. If there's an image, the `width` and `height` attributes represent the width and height in pixels.

Comment: What does "give it an image" mean? I don't see the label as an "image". May I have a demonstration of what this "image" thing is about?

Comment: The `Label` widget has an `image` attribute. You can set it to a one pixel image. By using the `compound` option you can have that pixel hidden under the text.

Comment: When I setted my width of my label to `width=100` along with `compound="center"` and adding in `image=pixel` while the label is below the `pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)`, I still don't see the label being an exact width in pixels. Is there something I have missed in my code?

Comment: @RonZhang: it is impossible for me to see without seeing your code. If what you say is true, the widget will be 100 pixels.

Comment: I have got the code to work as you've written, but I decided to change them all from ".pack" to ".grid", since I feel grids are more efficient and versatile. However, when I execute the code, it does push the text to that number of pixels long but does not push them to another line if the text is full but instead omits the words from the screen completely. Is there a way to push the words to another line if the text is full?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable that declares the max size of a label and then use it to fix the width/height issues on all label declarations as follows:

```
maxSizeX = 100
maxSizeY = 100
labelTitleText = "Program Name"
labelTitleTextSize = len(labelTitleText)
labelTitle = Label(root,
               text=labelTitleText,
               width=(maxSizeX-labelTitleTextSize),
               height=maxSizeY,
               font=(None, 40)
               )
```

Although I'm unsure as to how you would get character pixel width on the display if you could then you could change the above to:

```
maxSizeX = 100
maxSizeY = 100
labelTitleText = "Program Name"
labelTitleTextSize = len(labelTitleText) * pixelWidth
labelTitle = Label(root,
               text=labelTitleText,
               padx=(maxSizeX-labelTitleTextSize),
               pady=maxSizeY,
               font=(None, 40)
               )
```

Comment: It seems that when I tried to do this, I got this error about "labelTitleTextSize = labelTitleText.len()" and then the error message showed "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'". What should I do to fix?

Comment: I always get len() confused, the change is reflected above in the code. Please note that I also recently changed from padx/pady to width/height due to padding being specified in pixels, while width/height being specified in characters when dealing with text. If this helped please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hmm... It isn't quite center-aligned to my window length of 960px.

Comment: By the way, how do I make a reply about my current coding?

Comment: This is the only way to do what you want unless you know exactly how wide, in pixels, each character is when you display them. If you can get the exact width of said characters in pixels you would just change width/height to padx/pady respectively and by multiplying labelTitleTextSize by the width of a character before subtracting it from the maxsize.

Comment: You can edit the original post if you need to show updates by clicking the edit text directly under your post.

Comment: @vividpk21: no, this isn't the only way to center a label.The best solution is to ask tkinter to center the widget, and not use margins to simulate centering something.